# SQLite - retrieving ID of last row

Tags: c#, sqlite, ado.net, thread-safety

I face the usual problem of retrieving lastly added row ID. The problem is, that I want this operation to be as atomic as possible to be fully thread-safe. I use the [ADO.NET wrapper](http://system.data.sqlite.org) around SQLite.

This is my research:

- `SQLiteConnection` class provides a `LastInsertRowId` property, which returns a `RowId` of last successful insert operation. However, if some thread [had enough luck](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html) to push some data to table during evaluation of `LastInsertRowId`, I'll get some erroneous Id (mostly likely not the one I'm searching for).
- SQLite maintains a table called `sqlite_sequence`, where it stores values used for generating `AUTOINCREMENT` keys. I may manually increment one of the values and then insert a row with predefined Id value (I do something like this in MySQL using a stored procedure). The problem is, that if I want this solution to be safe, I'd have to implement selection from this table, incrementation and update as an atomic process and I don't know how to do it.
- Android API for SQLite contains an [`insert`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) method, which returns ID of lastly added row, but I cannot find such method in the wrapper I use.

So the question is: how to retreive ID of lastly added row **in a threadsafe manner**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way we handle this is to start a transaction, perform the insert or update, execute a SELECT [last_insert_rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid)() (retrieving its results), and then commit the transaction.

This should be atomic due to the transacted nature and the fact that this operation returns the information for the current connection, not any other connection to the DB.